# Cassandra 2.2.2 cannot create login user/role

Tags: cassandra, roles, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I recently updated my cassandra dev cluster to v2.2.2 which includes RoleManager support. I noticed recently that when creating a new user via CQL:

```
CREATE ROLE abc WITH PASSWORD = 'abcde' AND LOGIN = true;
```

or

```
CREATE USER abc WITH PASSWORD 'abcde';
```

In either case, after executing the above command the user cannot login. Inspecting the system_auth keyspace, I can see that a 'row' is written in the roles table but not in credentials or users.

If I manually insert the appropriate row into credentials and users, then and only then can my user login.

Note also that I cannot DROP the user 'abc' until the row has been manually inserted into credentials and users.

What's going on here - am I mis-using CREATE USER / CREATE ROLE? It seems to me that the CREATE operation should do the necessary setup. Or has the upgrade migration failed in some subtle way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the upgrade migration process completed successfully then you should see the following entries in the logs:

```
Completed conversion of legacy users
Completed conversion of legacy credentials
```

If this is the case then you need to manually drop the legacy tables with:

```
DROP TABLE system_auth.users;
DROP TABLE system_auth.credentials;
```

This comes from this [blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra). Cassandra will continue to use the legacy tables until they are dropped.

Comment: Solved thank you! Sadly I read that blog article, but clearly not all of it.